# selecting data in numpy array with different conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause, slice

I have a numpy array similar to:

```
a = np.array([1,1,1],
             [1,1,1],
             [2,1,1],
             [2,3,1],
             [2,3,1],
             [2,3,1],
             [3,4,1],
             [3,4,1],
             [3,4,1],
 ])
```

and would like to extract the rows where

```
a[0,:] >=2 and a[1,:] < 4
```

into b, resulting in:

```
b = np.array([2,1,1],
             [2,3,1],
             [2,3,1],
             [2,3,1],
 ])
```

I tried with

```
b = a[(a[0,:] >=2) & (a[1,:] < 4 )]
```

and

```
b = a[np.where((a[0,:] >=2) & (a[1,:] < 4 ))]
```

but that does not work. Any ideas?

Thanks!
Jorge

Comment: `a[0,:]` is the first row. Did you want the first column? The first column is `a[:, 0]`.

Comment: ah, that's it, basic mistake and could not spot it, sorry. thanks!

Comment: When debugging, I like to look at that inner boolean mask.  It's usually more productive to dig down and look at the pieces, rather than throw another layer of calculation on (e.g. the `where`).

Answer (score 4):

Your condition is using the first and second row of `a`, rather than the first and second column. `a[:, n]` selects the nth column, so you want

```
b = a[(a[:, 0] >= 2) & (a[:, 1] < 4)]
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in one step but you can do

```
b = a[a[:,0]>=2]
c = b[b[:,1]<4]

print c
```